# cursor.execute("INSERT INTO im_entry.test ("+entrym+") VALUES ('"+p+"');")

Tags: python, database, postgresql

```
   entrym='entry'
   entrym=entrym+ str(idx)

   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO im_entry.test ("+entrym+") VALUES ('"+p+"');")
```

I am using a query like this, where `entry1`, `entry2` etc. are my database tables. The program doesn't show any errors, but the `p` value does not get inserted in the db. What is wrong here? Please help me.

Answer (score 14):

By default, [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/) starts transactions for you automatically, which means that you have to tell it to commit. Note that `commit` is a method of the `connection`, not the `cursor`.

```
conn = psycopg2.connection('...')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("...")
conn.commit()
```

The intent is that you can group multiple statements together in a single transaction, so other queries won't see half-made changes, but also for performance reasons.

Also note that you should always use placeholders, instead of concatenating strings together.

E.g.:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO im_entry.test (colname) VALUES (%s)", [p])
```

Otherwise you risk making [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) possible.

Comment: my colname is varying in loop (entry1,entry2..etc) then how can i write the query

Comment: @Ria `cur.execute("INSERT INTO im_entry.test (%s) VALUES (%s)", [colname,p])` or even `cur.execute("INSERT INTO im_entry.test (entry%s) VALUES (%s)", [idx,p])`

Comment: @Ria sounds like you're trying to do something weird. Usually you'd always insert the same columns from a single code path. It's a huge topic, but you should look into database normalization.