# Getting MySQL Error

Tags: python, mysql

Trying to run a MySQL script via Python and it keeps giving me errors. Here is my MySQL:

```
c.execute("""INSERT into DATA(checkup_date)
VALUES(%s) WHERE machine_name = %s
""", (date, machine))
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE machine_name = 'TL-D04'\nVALUES('2011-11-11')' at line 2")
```

Comment: @JimGarrison: the `%s` syntax is how parameterised SQL in MySQLdb works.  In particular, note the lack of quotes around the `%s`.  Please do a Google search for the MySQLdb documentation and then throw away your comment.

Comment: Examining the source code for _mysql leads me to believe that the C API does not use prepared statements, and therefore is vulnerable to SQL Injection.  It does not appear that you can avoid it using the Python MySQLDB API. Sigh...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INSERT INTO ... VALUES ... WHERE ...` isn't valid SQL.  You can't add a `WHERE` clause to an `INSERT` statement.

I'm guessing you want to update the `checkup_date` column for a row currently in the `DATA` table, as opposed to inserting a new row.  If that's the case, try

```
UPDATE DATA SET checkup_date = %s WHERE machine_name = %s
```

instead.

Comment: This looks like it should work, but now it's telling me that inventory.data doesn't exist. I have a database named inventory with a table named data - it should work!

Comment: ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'inventory.DATA' doesn't exist")

Answer (score 0):

This thread should help you.

[cursor.execute("INSERT INTO im_entry.test ("+entrym+") VALUES ('"+p+"');")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342698/cursor-executeinsert-into-im-entry-test-entrym-values-p)

Looks like you have too many quotation marks

Comment: the """ is a Python way to denote that everything, including newlines, etc is a string value.

Comment: Thank you. That raises a new question: why should I include newlines or stuff executing a simple SQL sentence. The thread I called shows that it is not required to use placeholders