# Why is MySQL incrementing the autoincrement, but not inserting rows?

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, mysql-python

I am using xampp and python with MySQLdb. I am connecting and then running:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO customer SET name='aaa'")
```

No errors are raised, but no rows have been added to the database (as checked with pypmyadmin). However, the table *is* incrementing its autoincrement field.

What is going on and how do I stop it?

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342698/cursor-executeinsert-into-im-entry-test-entrym-values-p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Chasing Death noted. The correct syntax is

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO customer(name) VALUES('aaa')")
```

You also have to commit the transaction to actually store data in the database.

```
connection.commit()
```