# Another reason why you might receive "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" after INSERT INTO table [Python] [Flask] [sqlite3]

Tags: python, flask, sqlite

I am using:

- Flask 0.12.2
- Python 3.6.1

To connect to my database, I am using the following code snippet, from [Using SQLite 3 with Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/sqlite3/) document:

```python
import sqlite3
from flask import g

DATABASE = '/path/to/database.db'

def get_db():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
    db = g._database = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
    return db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_connection(exception):
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()
```

and after the following piece of code is executed:

```python
cursor = get_db().cursor()

hashed_password = werkzeug.security.generate_password_hash(request.form['password'], method='pbkdf2:sha512', salt_length=25)
activation_token = werkzeug.security.generate_password_hash(request.form['login'], method='pbkdf2:sha512', salt_length=25)

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Users (activation_token, login, email, password, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' (activation_token, request.form['login'], request.form['email'], hashed_password, request.form['name']))

cursor.close()
close_connection(None)
```

I am receiving:

```python
File "path/to/my_file.py", line 33, in register
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Users (activation_token, login, email, password, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' (activation_token, request.form['login'], request.form['email'], hashed_password, request.form['name']))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

What is the mistake here?

I sense it should be some trivial thing, though I wasn't able to pin it down. What adds to the confusion — `SELECT` queries in other places of my code are working just fine.

Comment: may be you need add the comma before params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself, while composing the question =).

Edited the title of the question accordingly.

The culprit turned out to be missing comma, between arguments of `cursor.execute()` (pretty trivial, just like I have anticipated).

So, line:

```python
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Users (activation_token, login, email, password, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' (activation_token, request.form['login'], request.form['email'], hashed_password, request.form['name']))
```

should be:

```python
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Users (activation_token, login, email, password, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (activation_token, request.form['login'], request.form['email'], hashed_password, request.form['name']))
```

I have also learned from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5342741/8554766), that in order for `INSERT` to actually happen, `connection.commit()` should be called after `cursor.execute('INSERT ...')` (single or multiple).

Thus, the final (revised) code, should look something like this:

```python
db_connection = get_db()
cursor = db_connection.cursor()

hashed_password = werkzeug.security.generate_password_hash(request.form['password'], method='pbkdf2:sha512', salt_length=25) 
activation_token = werkzeug.security.generate_password_hash(request.form['login'], method='pbkdf2:sha512', salt_length=25)

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Users (activation_token, login, email, password, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (activation_token, request.form['login'], request.form['email'], hashed_password, request.form['name']))
db_connection.commit()

cursor.close()
close_connection(None)
```